# AWS Serverless Image Handler Bucket Naming Problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create serverless image handler on AWS using the [this template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/serverless-image-handler/latest/serverless-image-handler.template)

I use the management console for that and even though I rename the bucket name in the configuration before creating the stack, it adds "**demowebsitebucket-**" and something random at the bucket name.
Here is the input where I put "**imagehandler**" as the origin S3 Bucket:

[image]

However the stack creates the bucket with this arn:

**arn:aws:s3:::imagehandler-demowebsitebucket-iafi34.....**

I downloaded and tried to find the renaming in the template but I could not figure out where the renaming is done. I also want to get rid of the random generated naming at the end if possible.

Comment: About the randomly generated name: It's a good practice to add it to s3 bucket names because they are global. So, most simple names (e.g. test, myBucket, etc.) are already being used. You can also try to create something like "company-name", "username-name", etc.

Comment: They are already like that Lucas, I just wanted not to share the company name here :) Do you have any idea about the second part of the bucket name which is created by the cloud formation?

Comment: I looked into the template file, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by renaming all occurrences of **Demo Website Bucket** to something else under **Resources** in the template file.

Demo Website Bucket was used there as a variable and it can be renamed to anything.